# Getting the element on each iteration.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list which may or may not be displayed on the screen. What I have to do now is check whether all the li in that list is visible or not. If the li indeed is visible then I want the iteration to stop and then get that particular element.

My attempt:-

```
var getList = $("ul li").each(function(){
                                    return $(this).is(":visible") ? false: true; 
                                    });
```

From my understanding what the above code is, it gets the array from the "ul li" selector and iterates with the function each. I need to break the iteration whenever I notice that the element is visible so the false is returned to get out of the loop.

So, now the problem is I don't know how to get that element back. I'm to a point where I can stop at the wanted element and gets stuck there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
var $firstVisible = $('ul li:visible').first();
```

Comment: Wow. Sorry @Pointy I almost marked your reply as the right one but this..this right here is genius.

Comment: Or `var firstVisible = $('ul li:visible:eq(0)');`

Comment: I don't know, but I doubt there would be any measurable difference.

Answer (score 2):

*edit* — do what @elclanrs answered for this particular problem; what's below is for when you can't do it with a clever built-in selector trick.

---

You can have the callback set a variable:

```
var visibleOne;
$("ul li").each(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    visibleOne = this; // or $(this) if you prefer
    return false;
  }
});
```

If you don't like the messy local variable, you could wrap the whole thing up as a jQuery add-on:

```
$.fn.findVisible = function() {
  var rv;

  this.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
      rv = $(this);
      return false;
    }
  });

  return rv;
};
```

Then:

```
var visibleOne = $('ul li').findVisible(); // either undefined or a new jQuery object
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.is()` returns a boolean, so:

`return $(this).is(":visible") ? false: true;` is unnecessary.

If you wanted to return the element, form your conditional as follows:

```
$("ul li").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":visible")) {
    return $(this);
  } 
});
```

Using `return` here will break the loop. It's a common practice when working with loops to abstract the matched results like so:

```
var matched = [];

$("ul li").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":visible")) {
    matched.push($(this))
  } 
});
```

This will add each `:visible` element to the matched array that will now be available for whatever you need :)

EDIT -

I missed your above line: "If the li indeed is visible then I want the iteration to *stop* and then get that particular element." Which means that means the answer using `$.first()` is pretty solid.